# What to select to back up from my system

Tags: 12.10, kubuntu, backup, deja-dup

I am using [Déjà Dup](https://launchpad.net/deja-dup) and trying to back it up so i can try install a legacy driver and in case the install fails I can just restore.

Tried Nepomuk but I dont understand not one bit of how it works so I searched on the internet and Déjà Dup was my best choice.

I selected all directories from filesystem but I get errors, first was the file "pagemap" from /proc directory, removed it and now I get some errors that some other files were not possilbe to backup.

So what directories to select from my filesystem so in case of a fail update or installment, to restore to its earlier state?

I've broken enough filesystems and getting sick of it.

I don't need partition cloning tools, I sarched others solutions,I cannot find one that works with my issues.

Example:Like system restore does for windows.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no equivalent of System Restore for Windows. Usually, if installing something breaks the system, it's easy to uninstall (if necessary from Recovery Mode); but, having said that, I understand your concern. The only suggestion I have, which you won't like, is either [RedoBackup](http://redobackup.org/) or [CloneZilla](http://clonezilla.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Two cautions:  1) Even as the author of Deja Dup, I still advocate simply copying files for one-off backups like this.  Deja Dup's usefullness is really for long term scheduled backups.

2) Deja Dup is geared more towards user data backups than system level backups.  That said, it should work.  It just has some warts like not being able to read some root-owned files as your regular user (which is normal, but DD won't prompt for permissions, it will just skip it and tell you it missed the file).

OK.  With those caveats, I would say just put / in your included folders list.  Deja Dup automatically skips common folders like /proc that shouldn't be backed up (unless you tell it explicitly to include it as you did).  See the help documentation for a full list of automatically excluded folders

Comment: deja-dup failed miserably, it gave permissions error :-| and canceled restoring and destroying my filsystem in the process.Think i will go with the cloning tool.....hopeing that clone doesn't get corrupted like most of the times it happened with norton ghost and other software i've tried acronis or which is, can't remember, gave away them a long time ago.